# optimizing a bash script chain - speed suggestions?

Tags: optimization, bash

i am testing an application that i wrote and want to test the solution my algorithm produces to a Monte carlo solution. I use the harddisk a lot and i was wondering if there was a solution that uses writing data to a file a lot less, since it is really slowing the process down.

The solutions are computed on the nodes of a cluster and examined using this script ( that runs on a node): Parameter $1 is an outputfile that the program wrote.

```
file=$1
script=/home/hefke/ov_paper/scripts
mv $file.out $file.out.old
grep "Overlapscore:" $file.monte > $file.grepped
awk '/./{print $2}' $file.grepped > $file.overlap
print "$script/std_dev.sh $file.overlap > $file.out"
$script/std_dev.sh $file.overlap > $file.out
cat $file.analy >> $file.out
cat "DONE" >> $file.out
```

Here is the script that collects the data on the main node. Analy and Monte files are my output files.

```
echo "Processing outputfiles for the mc_stdev_of_ov"
script=/home/hefke/ov_paper/scripts
curdir=`pwd`
folder=filedata
for file in `ls -1 $curdir/temp_output/$folder/*.analy| sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'|uniq`
do 
    echo $file
    $script/submitter.sh $curdir "processonefile.sh $file.out"
done
echo "$file.out now contains what stdtev spat out."
cat $curdir/temp_output/$folder/*.out >> $curdir/temp_output/tmp.out 
awk -f keys.awk $curdir/temp_output/tmp.out >> table.out
cat table.out
```

How can i optimize this procedure for speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store in files between each command. Instead, just redirect the output:

```
$script/std_dev.sh < <(grep "Overlapscore:" $file.monte | awk '/./{print $2}') > $file.out
```

The Bash Guide has an [excellent article about I/O](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput).

There's only one place where you write to tmp.out, and `awk` can take more than one file, so you can simplify those lines similarly:

```
awk -f keys.awk $curdir/temp_output/$folder/*.out
```

There's no [need to redirect to table.out and `cat`ing it afterwards](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter).

You [shouldn't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); you can simply loop over a glob:

```
for file in $curdir/temp_output/$folder/*.analy
    file="${file%.*}" # Remove extension
```

Comment: when i use script/std_dev.sh < <(grep "Overlapscore:" $file.monte | awk '/./{print $2}') > $file.out, it tells me :Missing name for redirect.

Comment: Are you sure you're [actually](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156#comment-288) running [Bash](http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6765)?

Comment: l0b0 you sir are a genius. as a matter of fact i am not :(. I am running the cshell. Thank you very much for your answer anyways :)

Comment: not relating to the question any more, but is there a way to group commands with the () as in bash in cshell?

Comment: Sorry @tarrasch, csh is one beast I've never had to handle, so I really don't know. Maybe food for a separate question on [USE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not related, but please don't mind if I use an "answer" to just comment : it seems I can't comment, maybe because I don't have enough points yet to do so...

Tarrasch, if you still use csh for your shell, please do not script in it.

Please read: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Use instead sh, bash (or even ksh). And better to stick to sh-only because that's what's all unix system rely on (and rc scripts, for example, are based on).